# Rundeck get code (or trigger changes) on Github and excute Job for remote nodes

Tags: github, automation, rundeck

I have a Rundeck Server and I just want to store some environment data (SSH key, AWS key, schedule, ...) and trigger code (or get code) from Github repo (all my script will storaged here). How can I config for this effort?

I known about add Nodes, storage keys, but I can not know about trigger from github. I have an idea about Rundeck will git clone Github repo, but don't know is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Git Plugin (https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/git-plugin) and then use the Git clone step for that https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/git-plugin#git-clone-workflow-step

Download from here: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/git-plugin/releases and put the jar file on rundeck libext directory, usually at /var/lib/rundeck/libext (you don't need to restart Rundeck). The configuration is very similar to SCM (https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/scm/git-plugin.html).

Answer (score 0):

I used git-plugin but It had error like that. Please look at my config:

[image]

[image]