# How to run custom command on rundeck host in Rundeck?

Tags: ansible, rundeck

I'm creating Rundeck job and I want to run a custom command (e.g. `git pull`) on Rundeck host itself within a job working on other nodes. I can see the *Command* or *Script* node steps, but is there a matching workflow step?

### Context

I'm pretty new to Rundeck, so here's some context on what I'm trying to achieve, maybe my whole design is wrong. I'm pretty familiar with Ansible though and I'm trying to integrate it with Rundeck to treat Rundeck as an executor of Ansible scripts

We're developing some software product, which is on-prem solution and is quite complex to install (requires deep OS configuration). We want to develop it in Continous Delivery fasion, as our cloud products are. So in git repository, along the product, we keep Ansible workspace (playbooks, roles, requirements, custom tasks - everything exept inventory) and on every commit Ansible workspace should be compatible with particular product version.

My current approach is following: build pipeline publishes as artifacts both build of the product and zipped Ansible workspace. Whenever we want to deploy it, we would run Rundeck job, which:

1. downloads Ansible workspace from artifacts (alternative idea: pulls repository in proper commit)
2. runs Ansible playbook (via Ansible workflow step), which does the stuff on selected nodes

How can I perform this first step? From what I can see I can run script or command on nodes (but in particular job run nodes are the target machines, not rundeck host). There is also SCM git plugin for Rundeck, but it can load jobs from repository, not Ansible workspace

Answer (score 0):

A good approach for that:

1. Integrate Rundeck with Ansible following [this](https://jwkenney.github.io/ansible-rundeck-integration/) (consider that Rundeck and Ansible must coexist in the same server).
2. Create a new job, by default new Rundeck jobs are configured to run locally.
3. In The first step you can add a "script step" (inline script) moving to the desired directory and the `git pull` command (also, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57675899/10426011) approach to cloning the repo if you need that).
4. Now, the next step could be the execution of your ansible playbook (Ansible Playbook Workflow Node Step) in your job.